# Are products made from illegal software also illegal?

Tags: copyright, software

Say a piece of software was aquired, and used, completely illegally, like a license key was hacked online or something, and many other products (say, for example, videos) were made with this illegal product. Are all of those products now also illegal?

For example, if they are videos, would they legally have to be removed from YouTube, since they were made in an illegal way? Why or why not?

Comment: Since the software maker likely doesn't care about your YouTube video, what about a different case: You created a recording using an illegal copy of some software, and your recording becomes a hit record producing a million dollar profits. Now the software maker found out. What happens next?

Comment: @gnasher729 ok thats also a good example, but theoretically if they chose to enforce it, even a minor video could [or could not] be considered illegal

Comment: YouTube (or any other platform) could remove them or not, according to its own policies, whether the works are legal or are not.

Comment: @Brandin whether the works are legal or not? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean YouTube (or any other platform) does not need to give some kind of legal justification for removing your video. If they decide to remove it, they will just remove it and cite a policy (term of service) to justify their decision.

Comment: @Brandin but how is that relevant to the question of whether or not its legal to keep the video up that was made with illegal software?

Comment: Asking in your question what YouTube would do probably is confusing the issue that you really want to ask about here. There are lots of reasons YouTube could remove your videos.

Comment: @Brandin "would they legally have to be removed from YouTube" -- is not referring to what youtube might do, its referring to how a law-abiding citizen would react, knowing the videos are illegal, towards the decision of keeping them online or not

Answer (score 5):

Presumably by "is illegal" you mean "violates copyright law". Copyright infringement is simply "copying / distributing without authorization", which refers to the original work and not some other work. The act of originally writing a book is not "copying" (likewise "taking a picture", etc), so the act of writing a book using pirated software is also not copying and not infringement. Nevertheless, the scope of remedies for the original infringement is not limited to just the cost of the infringed work. Under [17 USC 504(b)](https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap5.html),

> The copyright owner is entitled to recover the actual damages suffered
> by him or her as a result of the infringement, and **any profits of the
> infringer that are attributable to the infringement and are not taken
> into account in computing the actual damages**.

This is sufficiently open-ended that profits from the sale of an original work created using infringed software could be attributable to the infringement.

Comment: I either purchase or steal a word processor, then use it to write a bestseller that makes a million dollars. Is that profit attributable to the infringement, considering that I would have written the exact same book with legally purchased software?

Comment: the question isn't about the copyright of the content. the content itself is totally original, the question is only if its considered "stolen" from the producer of the software that was used to make it. if one steals someone's property and uses it to make something, that he wouldn't have been able to make otherwise, is that stealing (regarding the other product)? does he need to give the derived work back too??

Comment: In my example, there is no "derived work". Writing a manuscript using a word processor doesn't create a "derived work". If I take my printed manuscript to a publisher while driving a stolen car, would the rightful owner of the car have any rights to the manuscript? What if I created my printed manuscript using a stolen printer, or stolen printing paper? What if I created my manuscript with a stolen word processor? Is there a difference, and if yes, then why?

Comment: @gnasher729 exactly, this captures the point of the question